# How to find which port NodeJS uses?

Tags: node.js, linux, port

I tried with:

```
netstat -tupln
```

and this is the result:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4445            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8126          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

Comment: You can only see which process binds a port as root, try that command with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an access to your code, Simply go to `server.js` or whatever filename you have used. Port number is mentioned there. You may find something like

```
const port = process.env.APP_PORT || 80;
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
```